# Most active MUD?

Tags: muds

Since I have fond memories of playing MUDs I've been thinking about starting to play one a little.

However I found out that MUDs are a dying breed and only little of them have much activity left.

So I'm wondering where I can find out which MUDs still have a larger number of active players (say 50-100+ online?) and are decently well built?

Comment: I edited your question to ask for a site that shows MUDs that have a larger number of active players, or it would be closed as a game-rec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while since I've been at that scene, but the ultimate resource back then was [The MUD Connector](http://www.mudconnect.com/).

In particular, it has an [advanced search](http://www.mudconnect.com/cgi-bin/adv_search.cgi) page you can use to filter muds with a specific number of players online on average; for example, performing a search with the "100+ players" checkbox selected shows 23 MUDs.

Notice that

1. That search page is a bit clunky, for example some options are selected by checkboxes instead of radio buttons even when only one option is allowed
2. I believe the site's database depends mostly - if not entirely - on the feedback from the MUDs themselves. So if a MUD's admin don't update it often you may find that it has less or more players than advertised, and it's possible some popular MUDs might not be listed at all.

Despite these two caveats, this site was pretty accurate and popular back when I last used it... admittedly that was like a decade ago, but I hope it is still up-to-date and would help you too.

**EDIT**

I understand you already checked that site; I guess that when using the MUD connector, it's important to pay careful attention to the "updated" date for the MUD. For example, of these 23 MUDs mentioned above, only around 5 have been updated in the last 18 months; so I would skip the others and check these directly. Indeed, one of those 5, called the [3 Kingdoms](http://www.3k.org/), offers an [browser-accessible "who list"](http://www.3k.org/wholist.php) which, at the time of writing this, lists 90 players currently online.

Comment: MudConnector was the first site I checked, but I noticed the database is very obsolete and most of the "100+" MUDs aren't. That's why I came to ask community about it.

Comment: @Mavrik I guess you need to be more careful with the "last updated" date, I've edited my answer to show what I mean. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

http://mudstats.com/ might be useful to you; it tries to gather live statistics rather than relying on MUD operators' self-reporting of player activity, so hopefully showing up as meeting your playerbase criterion there means more.

Answer (score 2):

Back when I used to MUD on several different ones, [Top Mud Sites](http://www.topmudsites.com/) was generally regarded as a good indicator of activity.  If a MUD could get its players voting on that site, it was usually a safe bet for activity.  I personally played on [Achaea](http://www.achaea.com/) and there was always some activity on it.

Comment: I think Achaea did used to be pretty large.  The largest game I remember seeing in recent memory was Medevia - used to have hundreds of players on.  Dunno if it still does though.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but not that long ago BATmud was still kicking - to the point where the governing body paid a developer to build a custom MUD client.  I used to have quite a good time there, on and off for many years.  Check out www.bat.org for more info.